# MongoDB update many using the values of the user

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've written a function to execute hourly which looks up a user and finds some values and then pushes those values into a history collection that records the hourly updated values. I've written this so far as a test just finding a user by their ID but now I need to roll this out to my entire database of 50,000+ users.

From what I've read using updateMany is a lot more performant but I'm not entirely sure how to retrieve the document detail of the record that is being updated at the time.

Here is my code so far, which you can see I'm first looking up the user and then grabbing their valuation details which I'd like to then push into a history collection.

```
exports.updateUserValuationHistoric = () => {
    User.find({ _id: "609961fdd989613914ef7216" })
        .populate('UserValuationHistory')
        .exec((err, userDoc) => {
            if (err){
                console.log('[ERROR]: ', err)
            }
            const updatedValuationHistory = {
                totalValuation: userDoc[0].valuation.totalValuation,
                comicsValuation: userDoc[0].valuation.comicsValuation,
                collectiblesValuation: userDoc[0].valuation.collectiblesValuation,
                omiValuation: userDoc[0].valuation.omiValuation
            }
            UserValuationHistory.findOneAndUpdate(
                { user: userDoc[0]._id },
                { $push: {
                    'history': updatedValuationHistory
                    }},
                {upsert: true, new: true}
                )
                .exec((error, updated) => {
                    if (error){
                        console.log('[ERROR]: Unable to update the user valuation history.')
                    } else {
                        console.log('[SUCCESS]: User historic valuation has been updated.')
                    }
                })
        })
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

User model:
https://pastebin.com/7MWBVHf3

Historic model:
https://pastebin.com/nkTGztJY

Comment: at which line are you planing to use the `updateMany` here

Comment: Thanks @AbishekKumar I would assume it would be at line 2 to updateMany instead of finding just one user by id. The intention is to update all users, take their current valuation details, and push that into a new collection to record the history of those values.

Comment: I'm also assuming here that doing just `find({})` and then mapping every user (50,000+) is not going to be that performant and hang the single threaded backend express application?

Comment: `updateMany` is for the use case where you need to update multiple records with the same value, but in your case they each has separate values, which is derived from another collection `UserValuationHistory`

Comment: Ah I see, in that case what would be the best approach to this issue? Thanks!

Comment: can you share the models for required fields, I might try to run it on my local

Comment: Thank you @AbishekKumar I've added the models/pastebins into the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241207/discussion-between-abishek-kumar-and-alienbuild).